# Laravel 5 : Use different database for testing and local

Tags: php, laravel

How does one change database for development and testing on local system without editing the `.env` file each time?

I have found it quite inconvenient to practice *TDD* because of this.

Is it possible for a *Laravel* application to differentiate between normal development and testing so that it can choose the appropriate database?

Comment: That's exactly what the .env files are for. All you do is just keep several files, put one on the live server and then for development choose the env file you need.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## Create a testing database configuration in Laravel

Edit the `config\database.php` file and add a `testing` - array into the `connections` array:

```
'connections' => [
    'testing' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_TEST_DRIVER'),
        // more details on your testing database
    ]
]
```

Then add the necessary variables to your `.env`-file.

## Edit PHPUnit configuration

Open your `phpunit.xml`-file and add the following within your `<php>`-tag:

`<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>`

Now PHPUnit will run with the tests on the database you defined in the `testing` - array.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate, I did not have to edit `config\database.php`. All I had to do was set the `DB_CONNECTION` env variable from `phpunit.xml`, which is the later part of your solution. So what I have now is `<php><env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"></env></php>` in my phpunit.xml

Comment: Couldn't you add...    DB_CONNECTION=testing
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=test DB port
    DB_DATABASE=test DB name
    DB_USERNAME=Test DB user
    DB_PASSWORD=Test DB password   ... to the .env file and run php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 51):

For Laravel 5.5, the proper way to do this is create a testing environment file called `.env.testing`.  Here, you can define your testing environment, including the database you want to use for testing...

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test DB
DB_USERNAME=test DB user
DB_PASSWORD=test DB password
```

Then run this command...

```
php artisan config:cache --env=testing
```

This will configure the cache to the .env.testing file parameters.

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration) is a link to the documentation.

Comment: Didn't work till I ran ...
php artisan config:cache --env=testing

Comment: You have create a .env.testing file before running the command.   I would recommend the winning answer.  This method should really be used to switch between dev and production.  In the .env files you can define your testing server credentials, which I personally think is a better way to do it.

Comment: how to switch back to default environment?

Comment: To switch back to the .env parameters run php artisan config:cache without the '--env=' part.

Comment: I did a bash script that enters to testing environment, runs the tests and then enters to normal environment again, that way I found it easier. Ty

Answer (score 16):

If your testing database uses the same configuration but only its name is different, it would be enough to only change the selected database name by adding

```
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing_db_name"/>
```

to the file `phpunit.xml` in the `<php>` node

Answer (score 5):

For those, who want to use sqlite for testing

Create a test environment file and test.sqlite file

```
> cp .env .env.testing
> touch test.sqlite
```

In .env.testing file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=./test.sqlite
```

Followed by

```
php artisan config:cache --env=testing
```

Now again migrate your databases

```
php artisan migrate
```

if you need then seed it

```
php artisan db:seed
```

And whenever you want to use local env, run

```
php artisan config:cache --env=local
```

> Please note, env name can be found in .env file  as `APP_ENV`=local

Answer (score 0):

if you need a specific database for one of your unit tests, add this code at the start of your unit test

```
    $connections                                    = config('database.connections');
    $connections['single_test_database_connection'] = [
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'        => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database'    => 'single_test_database',
        'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset'     => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation'   => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'      => '',
        'strict'      => true,
        'engine'      => null,
    ];
    config()->set('database.connections', $connections);
    config()->set('database.default', 'single_test_database_connection');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a different .env file for each type of test. You can modify your tests/functional.suite.yml and  tests/unit.suite.yml something like this:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled: [Laravel5, FunctionalHelper, Asserts]
    config:
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

And this:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled: [Asserts, UnitHelper, Laravel5]
    config:
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.unittesting
```

Or you can simply modify your phpunit.xml and add environment vars like @Tijmen did above.